# How to select first element from git status in command line?

Tags: git, command-line

Let's say I have changes in 3 files in *git status*

```
git status

modified: app/views/index.html.erb
modified: GEMFILE
modified: config/routes.rb
```

And let's say I want to check `git-diff` of first in list

```
git diff app/views/index.html.erb
```

The question is: is there any way to select first or last item on git-status list(on keyboard) to avoid notorious copy/paste?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--porcelain` option of git status, from `man git-status`:

```
   --porcelain[=<version>]
       Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and
       regardless of user configuration. See below for details.
```

Then getting the first one could be something like (adapt it if your needs differ):

```
git diff $(git status --porcelain | cut -b4- | head -1)
```

Comment: If you're going to use `awk` you might as well do the `head -1` there too: `... | awk 'NR==1 {print $2}'`.

Comment: …and I'd simplify this to `git status --porcelain | cut -b4-`